# Image to showing when Loading Image from antoher Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2013, bitmapimage

**I'm using Visual Studio 2013 WPF and the MVVM Pattern.**

I have a Modular Solution, in 1 Project Solution I have many Projects.

- Common.Library (Class Library)

  This is basically my Library that will contain all the basic stuff e.g the class ViewModelBase.cs Implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. I also have Images folder that contains Images (jpg, png etc.) and another class called BinaryImageConverter.cs to Convert binary images to BitmapImages
- Customer (WPF Project)

  In here I have a user Control that has a Image control in it. I got my Model/View/ViewModels

CustomerModel : ViewModelBase

```
private BitmapImage _ProfilePicture;

private BitmapImage ProfilePicture
    {
        get { return this._ProfilePicture; }
        set
        {
            if (this._ProfilePicture == value)
                return;

            this._ProfilePicture = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProfilePicture");
        }
    }
```

BinaryImageConverter.cs

```
public BitmapImage BinaryPictureConverter(byte[] Picture)
    {
        BitmapImage Image;

        if (Picture == null)
            return null;

        Image = new BitmapImage();

        using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageStream.Write(Picture, 0, Picture.Length);
            imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            Image.BeginInit();
            Image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            Image.StreamSource = imageStream;
            Image.EndInit();
            Image.Freeze();
        }

        return Image;
    }
```

CustomerView.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultCustomerPicture" UriSource="/Common.Library;component/Images/DefaultCustomerPicture.jpg" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Image Name="ImgProfile" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Path=CustomerProfile.ProfilePicture, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultCustomerPicture}}" Stretch="Fill" />
```

I have a varbinary field to store my Images in the DB.

So I load my Data in my CustomerViewModel. Everything shows excepts my Image on my UserControl.
I have the FirstName and LastName displayed which is perfect but the Image doesn't appear.

EDIT :
Forgot to mention that my User Control is loaded in a ListBox and the ItemSource is binded to my CustomerProfile which is a ObservableCollection of the CustomerModel

```
<ListBox Name="listCustomers" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerProfile}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <vw:CustomerView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Ay reason why you do not directly create the MemoryStream from the byte array, like `new MemoryStream(Picture)`, thus avoiding the Write and Seek? And is `BinaryPictureConverter` used anywhere at all?

Comment: And is your `byte[]` array an encoded image (e.g., in an image format like PNG, JPG, or BMP), or is it raw bitmap data?

Comment: The `BinaryPictureConverter` receives the picture from the DB (I store the Image in the customer Table in a varbinary field), When viewing the Customers, it changes the varbinary into an BitmapImage so I can show it, now my issue is when the varbinary field in the table is null I need to show a Default Image, which is in the Common.Library Assembly, I've tried using the FallbackValue and the TargetNullValue yet without success I don't get any Xaml or Runtime Error, When I inserted the FallbackValue I can even see the picture but at runtime nothing shows for the customers that have no Image.

Answer (score 1):

WPF data binding works with **public** properties only:

```
public BitmapImage ProfilePicture
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Comment: WOW I'm an IDOT did not see that, Thanks Clemens and yes the BinaryPictureConverter is used when I Load my Data from the Customer Table the varbinary field that I talked about.

Thanks guys

Comment: Also, it seems like the TargetNullValue doesn't work, I can now see my Image of my customers but the one that doesn't have any, does not load the DefaultCustomerImage that it was suppose to ... why is that ?

Comment: Is `CustomerProfile` null for some customers?  If so, the binding produces an error (null reference) instead of `null`, so you should set both `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue` (which is applied when the binding fails/faults).

Comment: Actually the CustomerProfile is never null the CustomerProfile.ProfilePicture is null and if it's null he's suppose to go and fetch the DefaultCustomerImage.jpg I've tried putting the Fallbackvalue but still nothing I suppose the TargetNullValue is suppose to get the default Image if he finds null in the property ...

Comment: Any binding errors in the Output window?  Does `DefaultCustomerImage.jpg` have a build action of either Resource or Content (it must be one or the other for `pack` URIs to work)?  And if it's Content, do you have it set to copy to the output directory?  Can you display the image directly (without the binding)?

Comment: No Binding Errors, and Yes the `DefaultCustomerImage.jpg` has a build action of Resource

`<BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultCustomerPicture" UriSource="/Common.Library;component/Images/DefaultCustomerPicture.jpg" />`

When I add the Image without the binding I can see the Image in ImageControl but at RunTime it doesn't show it ...

`<Image Name="ImgProfile" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Source="{StaticResource DefaultCustomerPicture}" />`

Comment: Anyone that can help ? Thanks

Comment: Alright so after a fiew ressearch I've found that in my Common.Library/Images I had to change the Build Action of my Images to Resource and It worked